# Adjust background size on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

When you hover over the image, you will see that it will be replaced by the semi-transparent background in my code.

The transparent background is supposed to cover all the picture, however, it only covers the area taken by the text.

How do I make sure that it covers the whole picture, regardless of the text within the box?

```css
/*Programs*/

ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div.text-content {
  background: rgba(26,33,43,0.9);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div.text-content div {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.img-list li:hover div.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Events page */

/*Event link button*/

.btn {
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 42px;
border: 2px solid #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Roboto;
line-height: 28px;
font-size: 24px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
margin-right: 45px;
margin-left: 45px;
}

.btn:link {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:visited {
  color: #1b1c16;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1b1c16 !important;
}

.btn:active {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
}

/*All events button*/

.evens_btn {
background: ;
}

.events_btn>span{
color: #f9c70f;
font-family: Roboto;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 24px !important;
background: ;
text-decoration: none !important;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.events_btn>i{
color: #ffffff; 
margin-right: 15px; 
font-size: 50px;
}

.events_btn:link>i {
    color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:visited>i {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.events_btn:hover>i {
 color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:active>i {
  color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:link>span {
    color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:visited>span {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.events_btn:hover>span {
 color: #f9c70f ;
}

.events_btn:active>span {
  color: #f9c70f;
}
```

```html
<ul class="img-list">
  <li><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://www.sflsupport.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Programs-11.jpg" />                              
    <div class="text-content">
      <div>
       <h5 style="color: white; font-size: 38px; font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 600; line-height: 42px; letter-spacing: 2px;">WEBINAR<br/>ARCHIVE</h5>
       <hr style="border-top: 2px solid #ffffff; width: auto; margin: 10px 30px;"/>Throughout the years SFL has ammased the library of recorded webinars from some of the leading libertarian voices about numerous topics in philosophy, politics, and economics. How can the government fix the higher education bubble? What is Ayn Rand's theory of natural rights? Tune in to our videos for answers to these questions and many more.
      <br>
      <a class="btn" style="color: white; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 600; border: 3px solid white; letter-spacing: 2px;" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">READ MORE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove `display:table;` from `.text-content`. Also add `bottom:0;` to it.

Comment: if the content need to be centered vertically add another div as the direct child of .text-content and apply display: table CSS property to this.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `display: table;`, and for aligning the content vertically center use CSS Flexbox's `align-content` property.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
/*Programs*/

ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div.text-content {
  background: rgba(26,33,43,0.9);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div.text-content div {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.img-list li:hover div.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Events page */

/*Event link button*/

.btn {
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 42px;
border: 2px solid #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Roboto;
line-height: 28px;
font-size: 24px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
margin-right: 45px;
margin-left: 45px;
}

.btn:link {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:visited {
  color: #1b1c16;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1b1c16 !important;
}

.btn:active {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
}

/*All events button*/

.evens_btn {
background: ;
}

.events_btn>span{
color: #f9c70f;
font-family: Roboto;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 24px !important;
background: ;
text-decoration: none !important;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.events_btn>i{
color: #ffffff; 
margin-right: 15px; 
font-size: 50px;
}

.events_btn:link>i {
    color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:visited>i {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.events_btn:hover>i {
 color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:active>i {
  color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:link>span {
    color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:visited>span {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.events_btn:hover>span {
 color: #f9c70f ;
}

.events_btn:active>span {
  color: #f9c70f;
}
```

```html
<ul class="img-list"><li><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://www.sflsupport.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Programs-11.jpg" /><div class="text-content"><div><h5 style="color: white; font-size: 38px; font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 600; line-height: 42px; letter-spacing: 2px;">WEBINAR<br/>ARCHIVE</h5><hr style="border-top: 2px solid #ffffff; width: auto; margin: 10px 30px;"/>Throughout the years SFL has ammased the library of recorded webinars from some of the leading libertarian voices about numerous topics in philosophy, politics, and economics. How can the government fix the higher education bubble? What is Ayn Rand's theory of natural rights? Tune in to our videos for answers to these questions and many more.<br><a class="btn" style="color: white; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 600; border: 3px solid white; letter-spacing: 2px;" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div></div></li></ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it should be vertically centered as well. Thanks so much for the extra-mile! :)

Comment: @Ira It's my pleasure! If this answer really helped you, please accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

```css
/*Programs*/

ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div.text-content {
  background: rgba(26,33,43,0.9);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div.text-content div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.img-list li:hover div.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Events page */

/*Event link button*/

.btn {
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 42px;
border: 2px solid #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Roboto;
line-height: 28px;
font-size: 24px;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
margin-right: 45px;
margin-left: 45px;
}

.btn:link {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:visited {
  color: #1b1c16;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1b1c16 !important;
}

.btn:active {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
}

/*All events button*/

.evens_btn {
background: ;
}

.events_btn>span{
color: #f9c70f;
font-family: Roboto;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 24px !important;
background: ;
text-decoration: none !important;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.events_btn>i{
color: #ffffff; 
margin-right: 15px; 
font-size: 50px;
}

.events_btn:link>i {
    color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:visited>i {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.events_btn:hover>i {
 color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:active>i {
  color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:link>span {
    color: #f9c70f;
}

.events_btn:visited>span {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.events_btn:hover>span {
 color: #f9c70f ;
}

.events_btn:active>span {
  color: #f9c70f;
}
```

```html
<ul class="img-list"><li><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://www.sflsupport.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Programs-11.jpg" /><div class="text-content"><div><h5 style="color: white; font-size: 38px; font-family: Montserrat; font-weight: 600; line-height: 42px; letter-spacing: 2px;">WEBINAR<br/>ARCHIVE</h5><hr style="border-top: 2px solid #ffffff; width: auto; margin: 10px 30px;"/>Throughout the years SFL has ammased the library of recorded webinars from some of the leading libertarian voices about numerous topics in philosophy, politics, and economics. How can the government fix the higher education bubble? What is Ayn Rand's theory of natural rights? Tune in to our videos for answers to these questions and many more.<br><a class="btn" style="color: white; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 600; border: 3px solid white; letter-spacing: 2px;" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div></div></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this Css:

```
.text-content div{
height:1326px;
}
```